# What is wrong with my Singly Linked List implementation?

Tags: c, linked-list, singly-linked-list

Here's an attempt at implementing a singly linked list.
The problem is that when trying to print the list with `while (traverse != NULL)`, the program outputs 1, the data of the first node, but doesn't print the data of all the other nodes.  Am I linking the nodes incorrectly, and if so, where?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct node {
    int data;
    struct node *next;
} Node;

struct node *root;

int main(void) {
    Node *list, *traverse;
    /* root will always be the first of the list */
    root = malloc(sizeof(*list));

    list = root;

    list->data = 1;
    list->next = NULL;
    list = list->next;

    list = malloc(sizeof(*list));
    list->data = 2;
    list->next = NULL;
    list = list->next;

    list = malloc(sizeof(*list));
    list->data = 3;
    list->next = NULL;
    list = list->next;

    list = malloc(sizeof(*list));
    list->data = 4;
    list->next = NULL;
    list = list->next;

    list = malloc(sizeof(*list));
    list->data = 5;
    list->next = NULL;
    list = list->next;

    traverse = root;

    while (traverse != NULL) {
        printf("%d\n", traverse->data);
        traverse = traverse->next;
    }   
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
$ gcc main.c && ./a.out
1
```

Expected output:

```
$ gcc main.c && ./a.out
1
2
3
4
5
```

Update:
I've updated my source file just as all of you have suggested to this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct node {
    int data;
    struct node *next;
} Node;

struct node *root;

int main(void) {
    Node *list, *traverse;
    /* root will always be the first of the list */
    root = malloc(sizeof(*list));

    list = root;

    list->data = 1;
    list->next = malloc(sizeof(*list));

    list = list->next;
    list->data = 2;
    list->next = malloc(sizeof(*list));

    list = list->next;
    list->data = 3;
    list->next = malloc(sizeof(*list));

    list = list->next;
    list->data = 4;
    list->next = malloc(sizeof(*list));

    list = list->next;
    list->data = 5;
    list->next = NULL;

    traverse = root;

    while (traverse != NULL) {
        printf("%d\n", traverse->data);
        traverse = traverse->next;
    }   
    return 0;
}
```

Thank-you so much everyone!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you get the size of a pointer, like e.g. `sizeof(list)`, then you get the size of the *pointer* and not what it points to. You should do `sizeof *list` instead.

The next problem is this:

```
list = list->next;

list = malloc(sizeof(list));
```

The first line makes `list` point to where `list->next` is pointing, which is `NULL`. The next line *reassigns* the variable to point to some newly allocated memory. Nowhere do you actually *link* the new node into the list.

I suggest something like this instead:

```
list = root;

list->data = 1;
list->next = malloc(sizeof *list);
list = list->next;

list->data = 2;
// etc...
```

Comment: Thanks for catching that and bringing up sizeof(list) vs sizeof(*list)!

Answer (score 1):

There is a problem in the way you're linking different nodes. Look carefully at this section of code:

```
list->data = 1;
list->next = NULL;
list = list->next;

list = malloc(sizeof(*list));
list->data = 2;
list->next = NULL;
```

You're supposed to assign new node to previous node's next. But when you do `list = list->next`. Your list variable becomes `NULL`. Instead you should do:

```
list->data = 1;
list->next = NULL;

list->next = (node *)malloc(sizeof(list));
list = list->next;
list->data = 3;
list->next = NULL;


list->next = (node *)malloc(sizeof(list));
list = list->next;
list->data = 4;
list->next = NULL;
```

Answer (score 1):

Just re-check your code specifically for these two statements:

`list->next = NULL;
 list = list->next;`

Here list->next is pointing to NULL. And you are pointing to  list = list->next; Your assumption is incorrect here. Hence you are not getting your next elements properly.

First allocate memory for list->next and then try to point there. This ideally not my way of doing the things. however just to correct your logic I am writing the below lines of code:

```
list->data = 1;
list->next = malloc(sizeof(*list));
list = list->next;
```

You have to make this change for each of your node.

Answer (score 0):

Of course the `next` item of your root node is always `NULL`, since you do not assign any other value to it. Something like `root->next = another_node` is missing.

There are some good tutorials available that can help you with this implementation, e.g.

1. [learn-c.org](http://www.learn-c.org/en/Linked_lists)
2. [cprogramming.com](http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/c/lesson15.html)

Answer (score 0):

You should assign with malloc memory for your new nodes:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct node {
    int data;
    struct node *next
};

int main(void) {
    struct node *root, *list;
    int i;
    root = malloc(sizeof(struct node));
    list = root;
    root->next = NULL;

    list->data = 1;
    list->next = malloc(sizeof(struct node));
    list = list->next;

    list->data = 2;
    list->next = malloc(sizeof(struct node));
    list = list->next;

    list->data = 3;
    list->next = malloc(sizeof(struct node));
    list = list->next;

    list->data = 4;
    list->next = malloc(sizeof(struct node));
    list = list->next;

    list->data = 5;
    list->next = malloc(sizeof(struct node));
    list = list->next;

    list->next = NULL;
    while (root->next != NULL) {
        printf("%d\n", root->data);
        root = root->next;
    }
}
```

Test

```
1
2
3
4
5
```